# How to get business email id in response of paypal api

Tags: php, paypal

I Integrated Paypal in my website, I give **amount** and **business** email along with **cmd** to paypal when payment is successful it get back to my return URL with a query string

```
amt=67.00&cc=USD&st=Completed&tx=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But, I also want to get Email(Business) in my query string in which the payment has been done because I want to save it in my database.

What I want is some what like this:

```
amt=67.00&cc=USD&st=Completed&tx=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&email=example@paypal.com
```

Answer (score 3):

When you doing integration, at that time you have already merchant details like email, so you can directly put to database, why you want to get in return URL?

Comment: I only want to insert in database if the transaction is successful, at that time I don't have email...is their any alternate for this ?

Comment: But you can put statically on success url.